# matching two strings VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, conditional-statements

This one has really gotten me stumped but it seems like there is an easy soluition.

I have a code where I am matching two string to display `Failed` if they dont match and `Done` is if they do.

I first grab the text to append here

```
....
    Do While ie.getRowsInTables("tbl_business") ' table class name
    For Each tr In ie.tableRows
        For Each cell In tr.Cells
            If (InStr(cell.innerHTML, "SystemComments")) Then
                innerText = cell.innerText
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Exit Do
Loop
...
```

This is where I set the text area:

```
...
tmpString = ie.SetPageID("SystemComments", innerText & vbCrLf & "eATO: " & eMASSFieldAppender.cbATO.text & vbCrLf & "PSO: " & eMASSFieldAppender.tbPSO.text & vbCrLf & "AMP: " & eMASSFieldAppender.tbAMP)
...
```

This is where I try a conditional statment to spit out `done or failed`

```
...   
If (ie.GetEditSipPage(emass_id) = True) Then
    tmpString = ie.GetPageID("SystemComments")

    If (tmpString = innerText & vbCrLf & "eATO: " & eMASSFieldAppender.cbATO.text & vbCrLf & "PSO: " & eMASSFieldAppender.tbPSO.text & vbCrLf & "AMP: " & eMASSFieldAppender.tbAMP) Then

        Worksheets(wrksht).Cells(readRow, 2).value = "Done"
    Else
        Worksheets(wrksht).Cells(readRow, 2).value = "FAILED TO UPDATE"
    End If
...
```

Please note my code is fully functional but it is just not matching up those statements.

When I do a `Debug.Print` they appear to be the same exact statements.

What Am I missing?

Comment: Use ```and``` for boolean expressions and ```&``` for string concatentation...

Comment: right. i basically wanted to add onto what was already in the text area on the website.

Comment: Hmm.. so the strings are different. Did you check the line feed characters or additional spaces? You might also use some Editor and Change to a hex view... to compare character by character...

Comment: i thought about doing that but no i have not tried that, i thought maybe i may be a data type issue that i dont know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you're writing to innerHTML, there's no guarantee it will read back out exactly the same as when you put it in.

For example, if you set innerHTML = "A{six spaces}B" it will read back out as "A{one space}B" because multiple spaces typically get collapsed to a single space in HTML.

Bottom line, innerHTML is not a good place to store random text if you need it to come back unchanged..